# How to include a large external stylesheet and script in Google Apps Scripts Google Docs Extension

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I really want to use Material Design in my new Google Docs extension, but the [official](https://material.io) library's distribution contains 490 KB of CSS and JS. I want my add-on to load fast and work with Docs Offline, as well as not taking too much bandwidth.

Right now, I just have a `stylesheet.html` and a `javascript.html`, where I copy-and-pasted the external files and used templating to include them. Is there a way where I could support caching or somehow else improve speed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching frontend script are unavailable on Google Script for Web.

But you can put script to external HTTPS *(not only http!)* server and load it as external script – where is possible native caching via HTTP header (`Expires` or `Cache-Control`).

Is you haven't webhosting, you can use Google Cloud Storage. In Google Script editor open **Resources** > **Google Platform project…** > click to blue link with project name > hamburger menu > **Storage** > **Browse**. Here you can create bucket bounded to script's project, upload here any static files and click Share Publicly – you get URL of published script.

It is paid service, but [price is very optimistics](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing).

Comment: Thanks! I actually just realized I'm not allowed to use the libraries I linked to though, so I probably won't do this.

Comment: How you realized it? I am using it daily, all is works (it **must** be HTTPS, not HTTP only). Here is example how I link external JS/CSS to my Script: https://github.com/jakubboucek/google-script-groups-browser/blob/e5ac8c4302c952add32eb5953661f187804c789b/Index.html#L10

Comment: it was for Material Design and according to the rules we can't use Material specifically if I want to publish it as a Docs extension.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just saw that you're not supposed to use Material Design in Google Add-Ons. As such, I probably won't load any large external files.

Comment: Google is pretty lax with that requirement. Especially with GSuite itself leveraging Material Design more and more in its UIs.

Comment: @DimuDesigns but wouldn't it slow my extension (it would be in a Docs sidebar) way down?